# OSX etc/hosts not blocking one particular site

Tags: macos, hosts

I've used etc/hosts to block a lot of sites without issue, however I'm trying to add in filterbypass.me to the list but it won't work.

I've tried adding:
filterbypass.me as well as all the http/https/www varieties before it but it just won't work. Can someone figure out how to block this site?

Comment: Very interesting! I too added `127.0.0.1 filterbypass.me`, as well as the other permutations, to `/etc/hosts` and I could not `ping` it nor bring the site up in Firefox however Safari, while slow to load the URL, nonetheless it did load. So some how Safari is not playing by the same rules as `ping` and Firefox while other sites blocked in `/etc/hosts` will not load in Safari.  I too would like to know how and why Safari gets around what `ping` and Firefox can't.

Comment: @user3439894 & user139379 Please add your OS versions.

Comment: @klanomath, I'm not the author of the OP, so do you want my OS X version info or do you want the OP's OS X version info?  In either case, mine is OS X 10.8.5 and Safari is 6.2.3 (8537.85.12.18).

Comment: @user3439894 I was interested in both OS versions, yours and the OP's one

Comment: My OS is 10.10.3 and Chrome 44.0.2403.155